# Active Record Overrided Setter method gets called twice on update

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am getting this weird behaviour in model in Rails 6. I have a datetime attribute in rails model.
When I override setter method in model as:

```
  def start_date=(epoch_time)
    super(Time.at(epoch_time).utc)
  end
```

and create a new record, works perfectly fine.
But when I call update on the record, this setter method gets called twice, first time with passed value as `epoch_time` argument and second time with `nil` upon `Update` Query which breaks it.

EDITED:
I found out using "caller" inside method that it is being called from counter_culture gem. So, need to avoid it somehow?

Comment: Are there any other lifecycle callbacks on the model, such as any `before_save`s and such? Try logging `caller` inside this method to see the stack trace each time it is called.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz Actually, yes there were there but I even disabled them to give it a try and the problem was still the same.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz Ok thanks for your comment. I found out using caller method.Actually it was counter_culture triggering a second call.